# Distinct on multi-columns in sql

Tags: sql

I have this query in sql

```
select cartlines.id,cartlines.pageId,cartlines.quantity,cartlines.price
from orders
INNER JOIN
cartlines on(cartlines.orderId=orders.id)where userId=5
```

I want to get rows distinct by pageid ,so in the end I will not have rows with same pageid more then once(duplicate)

any Ideas

Thanks

Baaroz

Comment: Please post sample data for both tables, and a sample of what you would expect your output to be.

Comment: What about the other fields?  Meaning, if pageId 1 is associated with quantity 5 and 10 or price 1 and 2, what should those values be?  Sample data and desired results would be helpful.

Comment: `DISTINCT` does operate over all columns in the `SELECT` list, so we need to understand your special case better.

Comment: What version of SQL is this?

Comment: Also, are you just looking to get the top record for each pageID?

Comment: the database is very easy:table 1 is "order" include only orderid and userid,table2 is "cartlines" includes the fields above.my output should be only rows with no duplicate on pageid.so if there rows in output that contain same pageid only one will be shown in the output

Comment: @baaroz -- which row do you want to keep if there are dups -- does it matter?  And which RDBMS (mysql, oracle, sql server, ...)?

Comment: just like select distinct pageid

Comment: @sgeddes-- it doesnt matter! and I am using sql server

Comment: @valverij--top recored would be fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going by what you're expecting in the output and your comment that says "...if there rows in output that contain same pageid only one will be shown...," it *sounds* like you're trying to get the top record for each page ID. This can be achieved with `ROW_NUMBER()` and `PARTITION BY`:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY c.pageId ORDER BY c.pageID) rowNumber,
        c.id,
        c.pageId,
        c.quantity,
        c.price
    FROM orders o
    INNER JOIN cartlines c ON c.orderId = o.id 
    WHERE userId = 5 
) a
WHERE a.rowNumber = 1
```

You can also use `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ...` along with `TOP 1 WITH TIES`, but it runs a little slower (despite being WAY cleaner):

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES c.id, c.pageId, c.quantity, c.price
FROM orders o
    INNER JOIN cartlines c ON c.orderId = o.id 
WHERE userId = 5 
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY c.pageId ORDER BY c.pageID)
```

Comment: +1 -- didn't see this before I posted my solution.  Good answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to remove rows with all columns duplicated this is solved by simply adding a `distinct` in your query.

```
select distinct cartlines.id,cartlines.pageId,cartlines.quantity,cartlines.price
from orders
INNER JOIN
cartlines on(cartlines.orderId=orders.id)where userId=5
```

If however, this makes no difference, it means the other columns have different values, so the combinations of column values creates distinct (unique) rows.

As  Michael Berkowski  stated in comments:

> `DISTINCT` - does operate over all columns in the SELECT list, so we
>   need to understand your special case better.

In the case that simply adding distinct does not cover you, you need to also remove the columns that are different from row to row, or use aggregate functions to get aggregate values per cartlines.

Example - total quantity per distinct pageId:

```
select distinct cartlines.id,cartlines.pageId, sum(cartlines.quantity)
from orders
INNER JOIN
cartlines on(cartlines.orderId=orders.id)where userId=5
```

If this is still not what you wish, you need to give us data and specify better what it is you want.